# IE6 transparency+radio button can't be clicked

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, transparency, radio-button

**IE6:** when I place a partially transparent image in a div, the radio buttons in that div that overlap the non-transparent pixels of the image become unclickable. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
      div
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Olympic_flag_transparent.svg/200px-Olympic_flag_transparent.svg.png, sizingMethod='crop');
      }
      input
      {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 60px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="1"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you test the code, you can also try moving the button from (60, 40) to (40, 40) where the image is transparent, and voilà - the clicking is back in business again.

This bug might, or might not, be related to the [IE6 links transparency bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703277/ie6-png-bug-links-dont-work), but I'm not knowledgable enough to grasp any resemblence.

Have I done something wrong? Or how can I circumvent? Is there some other option apart from removing the `_filter:progid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found any real solution to the problem, so use one of the following workarounds:

- make image 100 % transparent where the radio button is (keep good margin, it's shape is probably not "round" but square or rectangular),
- remove the image entirely,
- combination of the above. :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the z-index of the radio button to higher than that of the transparent div?

```
div
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        z-index: 1;

        _filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Olympic_flag_transparent.svg/200px-Olympic_flag_transparent.svg.png, sizingMethod='crop');
      }
      input
      {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 60px;
        z-index: 999;
      }
```

Comment: Yes. Apparently you have not. Please test your code before replying.

Comment: Hey it was a suggestion. I do not have a copy of IE 6 with me to test you problem on. If you don't like people suggesting POSSIBLE answers then don't ask them to do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry I overreacted. My last question was spammed by people who came up with all sorts of irrelevant 'advice', guess I'm still a bit pissed. :)

Comment: No problem. we all have those days. Sorry I could not help.